# How to get the drawing cache of a menu in android?

Tags: android

I am using this code to get a screenshot of an activity:

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rootView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache();
```

However, if a menu or a submenu are not shown - then they won't be drawn on the bitmap even after they become visible.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache(); will return bitmap of that rootView only & menu is not a part of rootView.

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: you cannot capture screen without root access.

Comment: I do see the menu items... but not if they are hidden when the activity is opened... so it does not make sense.